# Display General 404 Error Page

Tags: php

If I have a static page at World/index.php that displays pages where the URL's match database values (e.g. MySite/World/New_York), I can write a query that fetches a 404 error page when visitors type in incorrect URL's (e.g. New_Yorc).

But if someone misspells the section name - e.g. MySite/Wurld - they're completely out of the loop. In Chrome, I get a generic error:

**Not Found
The requested URL /Wurld/ was not found on this server.**

How can I create an error page that will display sitewide in every instance where my regular 404 pages don't display?

(I'm working with PHP and MySQL.)

Comment: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/custom404.shtml e.g. `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html` in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an 404.php file with your error message and add this line to your .htaccess file located on the root of your server

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

all "page not found" pages will be automatically redirected to 404.php

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I created a custom error page and added this to my .htaccess file - ErrorDocument 404 /my404.php